# Protractor addLocator : how to get the object for the document

Tags: node.js

Im trying to create a custom locator in protractor using addLocator

My conf.js is

```
// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
//multiCapabilities: [{
//    browserName: 'firefox'
 // }, {
   // browserName: 'chrome'
  //}],
  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: ['DriverSpec.js'],
  onPrepare: function () {
  require('tech')(protractor);
  }
  //function (protractor) {
  protractor.by.addLocator('test', function (toState, opt_parentElement) {
    var using = opt_parentElement || document;
    var possibleAnchors = using.querySelectorAll(  toState );
    var result = undefined;

    if (possibleAnchors.length === 0) {
      result = null;
    } else if (possibleAnchors.length === 1) {
      result = possibleAnchors[0];
    } else {
      result = possibleAnchors;
    }

    return result;
  });
//};// The protractor object is available here.


  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 1000000
  }
};
```

Error shown :

```
C:\Users\jeevan.s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\conf\addLocator\Ne
w folder\conf.js:18
  By.addLocator('customLink',
    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at ConfigParser.addFileConfig (C:\Users\jeevan.s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\protractor\lib\configParser.js:183:20)
    at Object.init (C:\Users\jeevan.s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protracto
r\lib\launcher.js:35:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jeevan.s\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pr
otractor\lib\cli.js:129:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

Issues :

1) How to create a Protractor object
2) Trying to build object opt_parentElement by using this code lines

```
var using = browser.driver.findElement(By.css(".nav")); 
     buttons = using.querySelectorAll('active')
```

Its throwing the error as the "querySelectorAll" not found in the "using OBJECT"
Not able to access querySelectorAll method.
3). Could anyone can please help us addLocator with executable example. It would be great!!